# 1064 error in MySQL Command line client when trying to view table but works fine in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

So i created a database in MySQL Workbench and I am trying to view them on the MySQL Command Line Client because i want to do my queries there instead of the workbench.

Here's whats happening:

```
mysql> use policestation(crime);
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------------------+
| Tables_in_policestation(crime) |
+--------------------------------+
| accused                        |
| case                           |
| complainant                    |
| investigation_officer          |
| outcome                        |
| section_of_law                 |
+--------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from case;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case' at line 1

The same query works fine in MySQL Workbech. Also it works for all other tables in Command Line Client.

Comment: have you tried adding the schema name in front of the table name?  Like "SELECT * FROM crime.case"

Comment: yeah i did. still getting the same error. How come it works for all other tables but this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's b/c Case is a MySQL reserved keyword: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

You'll need to seround reserved keywords with tick marks not quotes.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `case`
```

Not the same as

```
SELECT * FROM 'case'
```

Also here is another helpful link:
[Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)